# What is the best alternative to BFD? Somethings to block DDoS and Brute Force Attacks?

Tags: ubuntu, security, brute-force-attacks

I have an Ubuntu server which is running Nginx and have a Wordpress site. I need good protection for it. Recently I found that  [BFD](http://www.rfxn.com/projects/brute-force-detection/) is causing some problems so I had to disable it. Does any one know of a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) and write custom rules.

regardless of the log-parser - make sure your logs are small - eg rotated daily.

Comment: I just read that fail2ban updates firewall rules... I have APF... Will it work with that?

Comment: @EApubs you can script any actions; from what i see apf is based on iptables anyway.

Comment: yup.. But the problem is, Apf loads its own rules at every startup... will that clear fail2ban's rules?

Comment: @EApubs fail to ban re-creates own chain on restart - that i'm sure about. during working -  you'll have to check.

Answer (score 0):

There's always [OSSEC](http://ossec.net) too. It's very configurable.